# Cost of cabin bags on Ryanair

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, ryanair

I'm flying with Ryanair and I will take a small bag  and one medium bag.
The medium bag doesn't have to be necessary in the cabin.

Do I have to buy a 10kg check-in bag or is the medium bag free of charge?

Comment: this is really lazy

Answer (score 3):

The only free of charge bag is one small personal bag on board which must fit under the seat in front of you (40cm x 20cm x 25cm), plus duty free bags. You’ll have to pay extra for your 10kg bag
https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/baggage/bag-policy